# Stripe payment logic

Tags: stripe-payments, weblogic, backend

I have a question about Stripe payment logics. I want to build a site for teachers and students.
Teachers and students share the available time for lessons. After lesson, teachers get paid from the students. And teachers can receive money once per half month or a month.(This withdraw operation must to be done automatically.)
I want to create a stripe account when signing up into my site.
I saw that there is custom stripe account concepts for this.
I cannot find out that clear logic for my scenario.
I hope anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start with reading this: https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide and then reach out to Support if you have specific questions: https://support.stripe.com/contact/email